# Submit forms from javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 2 input elements which I select start and end date using JavaScript:

```
<form name="form" method="POST" action="accesari.php">
<p>FROM:
<input type="text" id="min" name="min">
</p>
<p>TO:
<input type="text" id="max" name="max">
</p>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#min").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      $("#min").text(dateText);
    }
  });
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#max").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      $("#max").text(dateText);
    }
  });
});
 </script>
```

Then, in php I have another form which I use to select the client from a dropdown list filled with values from a SQL table:

```
echo ('<form action="accesari.php" method="post">');
$sql=mysqli_query($aBD->con,"SELECT DISTINCT DenClient FROM $tabel WHERE DenClient!='xxxx'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)){
$select= '<select name="select">';
$select.= '<option> </option>';
while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
$select.='<option>'.$rs['DenClient'].'</option>';
 }
}

$select.='</select>';
echo $select;
echo ('<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>');

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    ////is submitted
$client = $_POST['select'];

   // //DO STUFF WITH DATA
}
```

I would like to submit all of it at once. Is that possible?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: ajax: http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/

Answer (score 1):

just put it all together in the same page:

```
$sql=mysqli_query($aBD->con,"SELECT DISTINCT DenClient FROM $tabel WHERE DenClient!='xxxx'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)){
$select= '<select name="select">';
$select.= '<option> </option>';
while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
$select.='<option>'.$rs['DenClient'].'</option>';
 }
}

$select.='</select>';

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    ////is submitted
$client = $_POST['select'];

   // //DO STUFF WITH DATA
} ?>

<form name="form" method="POST" action="accesari.php">
<p>FROM:
<input type="text" id="min" name="min">
</p>
<p>TO:
<input type="text" id="max" name="max">
</p>
<? echo $select;?>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
</head>
 <body>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#min").datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'd-mm-yy',
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
  $("#min").text(dateText);
 }
 });
 });
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#max").datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'd-mm-yy',
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    $("#max").text(dateText);
   }
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have to embed all the Fields in one Form Tag as shown below.
First Build up the Select in PHP at the top of your File (Perhaps even before the opening HTML Tag...

```
        <?php
            $sql    = mysqli_query($aBD->con,"SELECT DISTINCT DenClient FROM $tabel WHERE DenClient!='xxxx'");
            if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)){
                $select= '<select name="select">';
                $select.= '<option> </option>';
                while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                    $select.='<option>'.$rs['DenClient'].'</option>';
                }
            }
            $select.='</select>';

            // PROCESS YOUR FORM...
            if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
                ////is submitted
                $client = $_POST['select'];

                // //DO STUFF WITH DATA
            }

        ?>
        <html>
            <head>
                <script>
                    // NO NEED FOR 2 SCRIPT BLOCK... ONE SHOULD DO.
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#min").datepicker({
                            dateFormat: 'd-mm-yy',
                            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                                $("#min").text(dateText);
                            }
                        });

                        $("#max").datepicker({
                            dateFormat: 'd-mm-yy',
                            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                                $("#max").text(dateText);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>
            </head>

            <body>
                <form name="form" method="POST" action="accesari.php">
                    <p>FROM:
                        <input type="text" id="min" name="min">
                    </p>
                    <p>TO:
                        <input type="text" id="max" name="max">
                    </p>
                    <!-- EMBED THE SELECT -->
                    <p>Select your option:
                        <?php echo $select; ?>
                    </p>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit"/>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
```